# Why I am not getting answers for my questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions

Why I am not getting answers for some of my latest questions on Stack Overflow. Is that not the proper place to ask such questions?

Is there any issue with the way I have asked?  OR formatting not proper? OR question not understandable?

Please let me know if I have to change how I asked the question?

Comment: Lucifer Owner of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598303/can-we-send-email-with-invalid-file-extention-in-attachment-through-php-script  post

Comment: No need to post code here. Code works for other files but not for some specific files. Ok le tme try once after posting code

Comment: I would just say to read this article [**Writing the perfect question**](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Just a guess here, but maybe no one who's read your question knows why its not working. I don't see why you're not willing to post your code, but I do see why you don't think it would help. As an aside, perhaps you could search for the opposite. *How do you block attachments with invalid extensions in PHP?*

Comment: Also read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're just not getting answers for the one question that you've posted multiple times.

Don't keep posting the same question.

Do more debugging and show what steps have been taken and more details on what is going wrong.  I agree that posting the code might not be that useful, but it will let people know that it might be a programming problem, and get them more engaged.  (Note: don't post ALL the code, just the relevant part)